# null pointer exception error while mentioning realm query

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, realm

Error said :

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>      Process: myname.myapp, PID: 8504
>      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity >ComponentInfo{myname.myapp/myname.myapp.MainActivity}: >java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method >'io.realm.RealmQuery io.realm.Realm.where(java.lang.Class)' on a null object >reference
>   ...
>   at myname.myapp.MainActivity.loadFoodlist(MainActivity.java:591)
>   at myname.myapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:91)

My code :

```
#591 RealmQuery<Food> query = realm.where(Food.class);
#91  foodList = loadFoodList(realm);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not initialized before call **realm**.

Comment: Sorry, before which line of code should I initialize the realm??

Comment: line no. 591....